# DbUtils excute insert sql with datatime column always has xx:xx:00 result

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-dbutils

When I use DbUtils to insert SQL with a datetime column in MySQL), I always get a result like 2015-03-25 17:35:**00**, when the desired result is 2015-03-25 17:35:20, any ideas?

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
update user set last_changed=date_add(now(), interval 1 minute);
```

Comment: Can you please your user table last_changed type and column properties?